# Uno R4 WiFi board is online but no OTA option for upload

Tags: ota, arduino-uno-r4-wifi

I have followed [these instructions](https://docs.arduino.cc/arduino-cloud/features/ota-getting-started?_gl=1*1rlls4d*_ga*Mjg3NTgyOTM5LjE2ODA4NjMxNDQ.*_ga_NEXN8H46L5*MTY5MDU3NDE2NS43MC4xLjE2OTA1NzQ4NzYuMC4wLjA.) to start using my new Uno R4 WiFi with the Arduino IoT Cloud. Everything works fine (even though sometimes the example screens do not exactly correspond with the actual screens). My Uno R4 WiFi is online and the online dashboard can switch the LED on and off even with the board powered from a battery and not physically connected via USB. **The only problem is that I still cannot upload a sketch via WiFi.** The instructions say:

> Once in the sketch tab, let’s open the board's drop down menu. There,
> a new option to connect our board should be available. The name of the
> board configured for the cloud will appear, followed by the
> Over-the-Air option.

But that drop down menu is not available and if I disconnect the USB I get `No associated device found` even though in Things-Setup the board is shown as being online.

Can someone explain what I am missing here? Or perhaps the Uno R4 WiFi is not compatible with the IoT cloud or the online IDE but that seems unlikely for a heavily advertised new WiFi product from Arduino.

Comment: it is not implemented yet for Uno R4

Comment: Where did you get the information that it is simply not implemented? It just seems odd to me as Arduino are adverising this device and its WiFi capabilities heavily yet I have not seen any mention that uploading per OTA is not implemented

Comment: @Juraj The Uno R4 WiFi is selectable in both the IoT Cloud and online editor, and sketches can be uploaded to it via USB. Only the OTA port appears to be a problem.

Comment: I looked into the library https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoIoTCloud/tree/master/src/utility/ota